# How to integrate part of cubic interpolation

Tags: math

I have the following function for cubic interpolation:

f(y<sub>0</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>2</sub>,y<sub>3</sub>,x) = y<sub>1</sub>+x/2*(y<sub>2</sub>-y<sub>0</sub>+x*(2*y<sub>0</sub>-5*y<sub>1</sub>+4*y<sub>2</sub>-y<sub>3</sub>+x*(3*(y<sub>1</sub>-y<sub>2</sub>)+y<sub>3</sub>-y<sub>0</sub>)))

I need to figure out the average of that function across some range of x, [x<sub>min</sub>, x<sub>max</sub>], typically 0-1, and I assume the best way would be to integrate.

I am currently just sampling the function many times across the range, which is stupid and computationally expensive.

I'd like to not be stupid about it, but since I am I guess I'll have to ask for help :)

Thanks <3

Comment: Calculate the integral F(x), then your 'average' is (F(x_max) - F(x_min))/(x_max - x_min). F(x) = (12ax + 6bx^2 + 4cx^3 + 3dx^4)/12 using MBo's definitions of a,b,c,d.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I understand, `yi` are parameters here, constants. So transform current form (Horner's scheme) to polynomial expression, using `a,b,c,d` coefficents (expressions with `yi`)

```
 y1+x/2*(y2-y0+x*(2y0-5y1+4y2-y3+x(3*(y1-y2)+y3-y0))) = 

 y1 + x*1/2*(y2-y0) + x^2*1/2*(2y0-5y1+4y2-y3) + x^3*1/2*(3*(y1-y2)+y3-y0) = 
 a          b                      c                           d
 a +  x*b +            x^2*c +                     x^3*d
```

and integrate it

```
 I(x) =  a*x + x^2/2*b + x^3/3*c + x^4/4*d + Const
```

Now definite integral over 0..1 x-interval is (re-check my calculations)

```
 a + 1/2*b + 1/3*c + 1/4*d = 
 y1 + 1/4*(y2-y0) + 1/6*(2y0-5y1+4y2-y3) + 1/8*(3*(y1-y2)+y3-y0) = 
 y0*(-1/4+1/3-1/8) + y1*(1-5/6+3/8) + y2*(1/4+2/3-3/8) + y3*(-1/6+1/8)=
 y0*(-1/24) + y1*13/24 + y2*13/24 + y3*(-1/24)=
 (-y0 + 13*y1+11*y2-y3) / 24
```

Integration over arbitrary intervals `x1..x2` is performed by similar way

```
DefiniteIntegral(x1..x2)  =   I(x2) - I(x1)
```

and average

```
Av = DefiniteIntegral(x1..x2) / (x2-x1)
```

Comment: @RonaldMcFüglethorn Did I understand you problem right?

Comment: Yes, I think you did, but the integral over 0-1 seems to be as simple as (y3 - 13 * y2 - 13 * y1 + y0) / -24. This did however help me understand a little more about how integrals work, particularly how and why it actually works to subtract the two points of the integral to get that range (I did have to divide by 2 though, to get the average across that range). It took me some thinking to understand, given I have not studied math, but I'm glad for that insight once it finally became clear and completely obvious, so I will gladly accept your answer.

Comment: OK, glad to help. Mistake in my calculations, corrected it.